# SSI Web javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ssi

I am currently having a problem with SSI's Custom Java Script Verification feature. I cannot make the program give me an error when a condition is not satisfied. I checked if javascript is enabled in my browser and it was. Also, I am sure to have it enabled in the survey. My code looks something like this:

```
var strErrorMessage= "";
var r1value = SSI_GetValue("q1_r1_c1");
var r2value = SSI_GetValue("q1_r2_c1");
if (r2value) < (r1value)
      {strErrorMessage="error";}
```

However, when I put a smaller number in r2, it does not give an error and it continues on to the next question.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: wrong syntax for the if statement: you have to this: `if (r2value < r1value)
      {strErrorMessage="error";}`

Comment: no luck, it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last part should be

```
if(r2value < r1value)
```

Right now you have mismatched parentheses.